# With DojoX Layout, is it possible to replace the content of a layout?

Tags: layout, dojo

I have a div in which a page is loaded with the DojoX Layout capability:

```
<div dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane"
                 adjustPaths="true"
                 renderStyles="true"
                 executeScripts="true"
                 href="my/page/containing/scripts/and/styles/in/a/sub/folder.html">
                Initial content, will be replace by href.
                paths in folder.html will be adjusted to match this page
        </div>
```

Is there an API I can use to later replace the content of this div with some other content from another page (other URI)?

Alex

Comment: I see there is a setHref() on ContentPane. Now how would I get the Dojo object for a given content pane I have in the page (as in the example above)?


Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id on the div (say id="myPane"), and write:

```
dijit.byId("myPane").setHref("path/page.html");
```

Alex